# Retrieve updated session variable after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax call to comments-set.php. In the php file I set a session variable to a random value. In the Ajax.done callback I'd like to retrieve the session variable.

I have verified that the session variable is being correctly set to a new random value but the old value is still displayed by the code in .done.

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit", function () {

    var comment = document.getElementById('comment').value
    var no_spam = document.getElementById('no_spam').value

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type:"POST", 
        url: "comments-set.php", 
        dataType: "html",
        data:{no_spam:no_spam, comment:comment}
    })
    .done(function(data) { 
        $("#display").html(data); 
        $('input[type="text"],textarea').val('');
        var nsq = '<label for="no_spam" style="color:#717171;" id="no_spam_Q"><?php echo $_SESSION['q']; ?></label>';
        $("#no_spam_Q").replaceWith(nsq);
    });

});
```

I assume (with my very limited knowledge!) this has something to do with Ajax being async or JS not waiting for the php to resolve. How can I get round this?

I've tried using events like Ajax.complete instead of doing it in the .done without success, I've even used onMouseUp on the button that triggers this code, figuring it gets fired in mouse down, so I'll get the session variable in mouse up, still no joy.

Comment: If you put `alert(data);` in your .done function, does it show your new session value?

Comment: No, it shows the old one, but I know the value has been changed correctly (I echo it in the php for debugging).